# Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5

Tags: php, mysql, database

Get this error on a social network university project i'm creating.

> Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5 in /customers/2/f/b/somesrandomsite.com/httpd.www/rnfunctions.php on line 63

Here's the PHP code in question...

```
function showProfile($user) {

    $UserID = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `rnprofiles` WHERE `user` = '$user'"), 0) or die(mysql_error());        
    $Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `user_id` = '$UserID'") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($ImageData = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query)) {

        echo '<p><a title="'.$user.'" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="'.$ImageData['location'].'"><img src="'.$ImageData['location'].'" border="" align="left" height="150" width="150" alt=""/></a></p>';// Display each image belonging to the user
    }

    $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM rnprofiles WHERE user='$user'") or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=left /><br />";
    }

}
```

If anyone had any thoughts it'd be a great help.

Comment: Never nest `mysql_query()` inside any `mysql_result()` or `mysql_fetch_*()` call. If the query fails or returns no rows ( as is your case), which is not an error condition, the subsequent outer call will fail with error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular error message, but it appears to me there are no results in the result set. Never assume what a `mysql_query` call returns! It may be `false`, it may be an empty set, it may be anything. Do some error handling!

Comment: Verify your first query up there. Most likely, the variable `$user` does not contain what you expect it to contain...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: @hjpotter92 man you guys get a lot of use out of that factoid...

Comment: @sevenseacat http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: @hjpotter92 I figured it was something like that :p Nice.

Answer (score 1):

whenever you will use `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);`

because `$result` only stores the resource id. So each time you will iterate it in loop it goes to another row if exists.

To get all data you have to use while loop like below

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  //do your operation
}
```

Comment: where abouts in the code should this be applied?

Comment: Aha, It is just a conceptual code. You can just apply the code here you need fetch_row and data in array.

Answer (score 1):

> Calls to mysql_result() should not be mixed with calls to other
>   functions that deal with the result set.

[refer to here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php#)

So, change

```
$UserID = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `rnprofiles` WHERE `user` = '$user'"), 0) or die(mysql_error());
```

to this

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `rnprofiles` WHERE `user` = '$user'") or die(mysql_error());
$UserID = mysql_result($result,0);
```

Also, there is a syntax error. change `queryMysql` to `mysql_query`

Comment: When i apply these changes this error appears as there is an extra bracket after the second parameter.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /customers/2/f/b/somesite.com/httpd.www/rnfunctions.php on line 64

Comment: sorry...i edited my answer

Comment: Still get this error

´Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 5´

Comment: perhaps there is no record in `$result`. are you sure your query returns something? try put real user instead of `$user` to know if your query works.

Comment: `Unable to jump to row 0 ...` means your query does not put any record. try to use `like`. it should be `WHERE user LIKE '%".$user."%'"`

Comment: that also had no effect